# Add group to multiple layers

Tags: konvajs

I am trying to add a group to multiple layers. But when I do, the group is only attached to the last layer. Which makes total sense but I'm looking for a way to avoid this.

**Why I am doing this in the first place:**

The user can chose to make a preset. This includes all nodes the user wants on multiple layers.
An example could be a logo in the top right corner. So the logo needs to be on every layer in top right corner.

So I wonder if there is a way to do like so:

```
layer1.add(presetGroup)
layer2.add(presetGroup)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a note to say that you should avoid having 'too many' layers as a layer in Konva is the same as an HTML canvas plus the Konva wrapper. There is no hard limit that I can give because it depends on many parameters of your solution and how it works. But in general if you find yourself using > 5 layers I would refactor.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am actually using a lot of layers. What do you recommend in my case? It could have 1 very very large complicated layer with multiple groups. What makes me think multiple "smaller" layers are better.

Comment: Like I said, there is no fixed rule. But each Konva layer is a wrapper for an HTML5 canvas so has the overheads of any redrawing that you might call for. Read the [optimisation tips](https://konvajs.org/docs/performance/All_Performance_Tips.html) on the Konva docs site.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the cache can be used to actually clone layers, groups and nodes. It solved my problem.